# python compound regex to extract text between different tags in different documents

Tags: python, regex

I have two types of documents containing text I want to copy and save. One document type has the interesting text delimited by tags named TAGSTART and TAGEND. The other document type has the interesting text delimted by CORESTART and COREEND. Here are two samples:

```
intro intro intro intro intro intro
BEGIN A This is where some text starts
That is not interesting or wanted
CORESTART save text A save text A save text A save text A 
save text A save text A save text A save text A save text A 
save text A COREEND
This is an addendum that is not needed but is just in the way
END A outro outro outro outro outro outro 
outro outro outro outro outro outro outro
```

.

```
intro intro intro intro intro intro
INIT B This is where some text starts
That is not interesting or wanted
TAGSTART B save text B save text B save text B save text B 
save text B save text B save text B save text B save text B 
save text B TAGEND B
This is an addendum that is not needed but is just in the way
TERM B outro outro outro outro outro outro 
outro outro outro outro outro outro outro
```

and this python script works for the first type of file

```
import os
import re
import codecs
# walk the directory tree
rootDir = '.'
for dirName, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
    #    exclude hidden files and directories
    files = [f for f in files if not f[0] == '.']
    subdirs[:] = [d for d in subdirs if not d[0] == '.']
    for fname in files:
         if fname.endswith(('.txt', '.TXT')):
            #    create the full path
            filename = os.path.join(dirName, fname)
            with codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as infile, codecs.open('SAVED.txt', 'a',encoding='utf-8') as outfile: 
                stuff = infile.read()
                saveTEXT = '\n' + ''.join(re.findall(r"CORESTART(.+?)COREEND", stuff, re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)) + '\n'
                outfile.write(saveTEXT)
                infile.close()
                outfile.close()
```

and if I change the regex to

```
      saveTEXT = '\n' + ''.join(re.findall(r"TAGSTART B(.+?)TAGEND B", stuff, re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)) + '\n'
```

I can get what I want from the second type of file. However the compound regex fails:

```
      saveTEXT = '\n' + ''.join(re.findall(r"CORESTART|TAGSTART B(.+?)COREEND|TAGEND B", stuff, re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)) + '\n'
```

Nothing is found. I tried enclosing the raw regex in parens but then I get an error that the regex is expecting a string but finding a tuple. I tried setting off the words in the regex with \b to indicate word boundaries like so

```
       saveTEXT = '\n' + ''.join(re.findall(r"\bCORESTART B\b|\bTAGSTART B\b(.+?)\bCOREEND B\b|\bTAGEND B\b", stuff, re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)) + '\n'
```

but this also comes up empty. My mind was totally blown when I tried this for the raw string:

```
[\bCORESTART\b|\bTAGSTART B\b](.+?)[\bCOREEND\b|\bTAGEND B\b]
```

Could I have some direction on what I have overlooked? My brain is cooked.

Comment: Well, this approach (`r"\b(?:CORESTART B|TAGSTART B)\b(.+?)\b(?:COREEND B|TAGEND B)\b"`) is not safe. You can get text between `CORESTART B` and `TAGEND B`.

Comment: I think bobblebubble's regex is the correct way to go if you allow some small deviations (like "CORESTART" may be followed by a space + "B" that you do not want to get from the match): [`(TAG|CORE)START(?: B)?(.+?)(\1END(?: B)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/vJ6dJ4/1). You will also have to extract the string with `re.finditer`.

Comment: WOW! it works. Yes I see your concern. Also, if one of the tags happens to be missing or is misspelled in the document, the regex will totally skip that document. Finally, it's interesting that it appends the saved text in reverse order - the text for document B is saved first then the text for document A

Comment: thank you. I'll give you credit if you post your comment as an answer.

Comment: who is bobblebubble?

Comment: An SO user who posted `(TAG|CORE)START B(.+?)(\1END B)` regex, but deleted the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@bobblebubble's regex in the deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35651929/3832970) is the correct way to go if you allow some small deviations (like "CORESTART" may be followed by a space + "B" that you do not want to get from the match). That is, I suggest adding `(?: B)?` to that `(TAG|CORE)START B(.+?)(\1END B)` regex:

```
(TAG|CORE)START(?: B)?(.+?)(\1END(?: B)?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vJ6dJ4/1)

You will also have to extract the string with `re.finditer`, as `re.findall` will extract all capature group values.

[IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/HAMEjA):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(TAG|CORE)START(?: B)?(.+?)(\1END(?: B)?)', re.DOTALL)
test_str = "intro intro intro intro intro intro\nBEGIN A This is where some text starts\nThat is not interesting or wanted\nCORESTART save text A save text A save text A save text A \nsave text A save text A save text A save text A save text A \nsave text A COREEND\nThis is an addendum that is not needed but is just in the way\nEND A outro outro outro outro outro outro \noutro outro outro outro outro outro outro \n.\n\nintro intro intro intro intro intro\nINIT B This is where some text starts\nThat is not interesting or wanted\nTAGSTART B save text B save text B save text B save text B \nsave text B save text B save text B save text B save text B \nsave text B TAGEND B\nThis is an addendum that is not needed but is just in the way\nTERM B outro outro outro outro outro outro \noutro outro outro outro outro outro outro "
print([x.group(2) for x in p.finditer(test_str)])
```

Please note that `re.MULTILINE` is redundant in your regex because this flag redefines the behavior of `^` and `$` anchors that start matching the start and end of the *line* rather than the whole string (respectively). Thus, I left it out of the regex declaration.

Comment: Yes, didn't try much, working :) yours would do but also matches `TAGSTART B` ... `TAGEND C`.

Comment: @bobblebubble: Your idea is anyway correct, I just focused on grouping first, and you started to eye-parse the patterns, and did a very good job.

Comment: this has to be one of the most positive and satisfying experiences I have ever had on SO. thank you both. that tells you how much I struggled with this. But it also tells you that clear, concise answers are treasure. Care to tell me who to vote for? Please dont say Trump (Hit1er?)

Comment: I am no US citizen, vote for anyone who you think is worth.